# Move Second Column of Each Row to a New Next Row

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I can move every second row into the second column of the previous row by:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?FS:RS)}' file > newfile
```

But I can't do it the other way around. What I have is as below:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

I need

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

I have checked several similar column-row shifting questions, but couldn't figure out my case. Thanks!

Comment: You know awk well enough to write `awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?FS:RS)}' file` but can't figure out to write `awk '{print $1 RS $2}' file` instead??? I highly recommend you start reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins so you get a basic understanding of the scripts people are writing for you.

Comment: I totally agree with you :D like couldnt agree more! And I had already bought a book about sed&awk, in my to-do list among lots of other things. But I didn't ask for the script above, I had found it in another post. Cheers

Comment: Throw away any book you have about sed&awk as you do NOT need a book to learn the only constructs you should use in sed, s, g, and p (with -n), and the awk part of that book will be out of date and incomplete. The ONLY book anyone should be trying to learn awk from is the one I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful info, Ed. I have checked the book you mentioned and it looks great indeed. I am moving to bioinformatics from biology so kind of hard to learn the languages from the scratch, I am only doing that for Python, but I can ditch sed as awk already is better than sed. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `tr`

```
cat file | tr ' ' '\n'
```

or `sed`

```
sed -r 's/ /\n/g' file
```

you get,

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Comment: Lose the UUOC: `tr ' ' '\n' < file`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk command with `OFS='\n'` to get output field separator as newline after forcing awk to rewrite each record with `$1=$1` trick:

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' OFS='\n' file
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

You can also use `grep -o`:

```
grep -Eo '\w+' file
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `xargs` with 1 record at a time,

```
xargs -n1 <file
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

From the `man xargs` page

> -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
>               Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the
>               -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.